# JavaScript unit testing with external module

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, nodeunit

I am working on an existing node project where the code structure for most of the js files looks something like following.

```
    var mod1 = require("mod1");
    var mod2 = require("mod2");
    var modn = require("moden");


    function func1(data, callback) {
        // Do some validation with data etc.. 
        // Use one or more imported modules here 

    }

    function func2(data, callback) {
        // Do some validation with data etc.. 
        // Use one or more imported modules here 

    }


    exports.func1 = func1
    exports.func2 = func2
```

How can unit test func1, while not being dependent on the imported modules? How can I mock/stub them? 
I come from the Java world so I am familiar with the mocking concepts, but here I am not sure how can I mock the globally declared module imports using require.

Currently we are using nodeunit for the unit testing purpose, but it tests very small part of the code.

I am reading about simon.js and testdouble but not sure how to use them to mock the global variables.

Any help/direction is appreciated.

Comment: I'm supposing that `func1` uses some of the depencies internally, for example, `mod1`. If `func1` depends on the required modules. Why would you want to mock it instead of using the real dependencies?

Comment: http://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/

Comment: https://github.com/testdouble/testdouble.js/blob/master/docs/7-replacing-dependencies.md#replacing-real-dependencies-with-test-doubles

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy You are right about the dependency.  Imaging the dependency could be to 3rd party call or database call. I don't want to have those services available for the unit testing. Because I am interested in the testing the functionality for the function I am writing. Also if I live the real dependencies, it is possible that they might throw some error at some instance, which would break the unit test.

Comment: @JigarPatel so, supposedly, if `mod1` is a "database call", and `func1` is used to do something with a data received from the database call. Then `func1` should receive the data that is expected via parameter, instead of using `mod1` by accessing it from the outer scope. In that way, you would have `file1` located on another file which doesn't require `mod1` or no other modules. Does that makes sense for your case?

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy I respectfully have to disagree with you. The comments posted by Yosef is very close to what I am looking for.

Comment: @JigarPatel I see, that is what you´re looking for, and is not a problem at all that you disagree. It´s a good thing. But let's just brainstorm a bit about it. Look at the example on the first link that Yosef posted. There, 'existsSyncStub' is being used instead of the real one 'existsSync', and in that case, 'existsSyncStub' always works. So, you gain the control to make 'existsSyncStub' behave in a way that you want, in order to test 'doesFileExist' for some scenarios. But, at the end, 'doesFileExist' is inherently dependent of the real method 'existsSync'.

Comment: @JigarPatel What if 'fs' is upgraded to a new version, where 'existsSync' is broken and it is not working anymore as it should? Your test will say that everything is ok, because 'existsSyncStub' was planned to be ok, but then, when using 'doesFileExist' for real, it would be in fact broken.

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy I understand that, but that is not what I am testing in this example code. I only care about functional testing of func1.

Answer (score 0):

For overriding dependencies during testing I recommend to use in your situation the https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire module

For quick exmple I paste example from project github

`foo.js:`

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports.extnameAllCaps = function (file) {
 return path.extname(file).toUpperCase();
};

module.exports.basenameAllCaps = function (file) {
 return path.basename(file).toUpperCase();
}
```

`foo.test.js:`

```
var proxyquire =  require('proxyquire')
, assert     =  require('assert')
, pathStub   =  { };

// when no overrides are specified, path.extname behaves normally
var foo = proxyquire('./foo', { 'path': pathStub });
assert.equal(foo.extnameAllCaps('file.txt'), '.TXT');
```